# How can I clear TextOut?

Tags: c++, winapi

How can I delete or hide the current textout to add new text? currently, as he adds another textout, the text overlaps the text.
I tried to use `InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);` but I don't see any difference.

```cpp
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
                TextOut(hdc, 5, 5, text.c_str(), _tcslen(_T(text.c_str())));
                EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @HansPassant I have wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);

Answer (score 1):

Your call to `TextOut` is in your `WM_PAINT` handler. This means that the text will always be drawn on each `WM_PAINT`, making your call to `InvalidateRect` practically useless.

One way to fix this would be to have a boolean (`drawText`) to indicate whether you want to draw the text or not. Then in your function to clear the text:

```
drawText = FALSE;
InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
```

And in your `WndProc`:

```
case WM_PAINT:
    {
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        if(drawText)
            TextOut(hdc, 5, 5, text.c_str(), _tcslen(_T(text.c_str())));
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    }
    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the `InvalidateRect` call will trigger a `WM_PAINT` message, causing TextOut() to be called again. The answer of @mnistic is a good solution. But I think you should really put `TextOut` method into the real event handling (such as OnButtonClickEvent) instead of putting it into `WM_PAINT`.

Answer (score 0):

Another technique is to re-draw the text with the background colour, something like:

```
HDC hdc = ::GetDC(this->m_hWnd);
SetBkMode(hdc, TRANSPARENT);

SetTextColor(hdc, clrBackground);
TextOut(hdc, 5, 5, text.c_str(), _tcslen(_T(text.c_str())));

UpdateTextSomewhere(&text);

SetTextColor(hdc, clrText);
TextOut(hdc, 5, 5, text.c_str(), _tcslen(_T(text.c_str())));
::ReleaseDC(this->m_hWnd, hdc);
```

`clrX` are of type `COLORREF`. They might be set up in the form constructor or`OnInitDialog` e.g. `clrText = RGB(0, 0, 0);`.

This technique only works if the form background is a single, solid colour.